How to run GUI application under dotnet-coverage?
Using the .NET tool dotnet-coverage I've been collecting coverage data from applications. But there seems to be an issue with GUI applications. Starting the application in command line like this:
MyProgram.exe

Returns control the command line interface as I hit the Application.Run(MyForm) line. This is presumably by design, but where and when is control returned to caller in the code? And how to suppress it?
The way this interferes with dotnet-coverage is the coverage report is finalized as I hit that line. Because the commands sent to the tool is just a command and arguments I can't use the usual CMD/powershell tricks to wait for the application to actually finish, since those would only wait for the dotnet-coverage tool to finish. So I'm left with somehow suppressing the behavior where control is returned to caller on hitting Application.Run.
For reference this is the line using dotnet-coverage to collect coverage information:
dotnet-coverage collect MyProgram.exe

Any ideas or workarounds?

Building as console application (OutputType=Exe) rather than windows application (OutputType=WinExe) seems to at least have the console wait properly. Standby for final validation.

Changing project OutputType from WinExe to Exe fixed it.
